# laravel - target class does not exist error when using ajax to update form with formdata

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am using Laravel with AJAX to send form update request. With other method such as POST request, everything works fine. I managed to do Update method as well but with a different method which is defining it on data field one by one. But since my new form has a lot of input field, I try to serialize it using FormData, but then the error of target class does not exist came out. The error in specific is

> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Form] does not exist

The Controller that I am trying to send to is named FormController, somehow from the error it removes the "Controller" part.

I am not sure what causes it, hope someone would enlighten me on this issue, thank you.

**Laravel Blade**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formUpdate">
   @csrf
   <input type="hidden" name="flowId" id="flowId" value="1">
   <input type="hidden" name="formId" id="formId" value="{{ $formData->id }}">
   @component('components.form.form-section-a', ['formData' => $formData, 'projectMember' => $projectMember])
   @endcomponent

<div class="grid w-full">
    <div class="sm:px-1 md:px-0">
       <button class="border-green-600 bg-green-600 w-full py-2 rounded mt-3 text-white submitForm" type="submit">Update</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**AJAX Script**

```
$("#formUpdate").on("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var formId = $('#formId').val();
        var url = '/Form/' + formId;
        var form = this;
        formData = new FormData(form);
        console.log(Array.from(formData));

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "PATCH",
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            data: formData,
            // dataType:'json',
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                // return false;
            },
        });
    });
```

Comment: Check your route and clear route cache first.

Comment: are you making a reference to a class named `Form` in your Controller?

Comment: @lagbox Thank you, I did have a class named Form, which I don't remember why it is there or I changed it. After removed, I can update it just fine, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

in your button add data-url="route('Form')" or console.log(url); first then check